# angular 4 - custom *ngFor for generic array

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to customize a template like this within a custom directive (app-search-dropdown):

```
<li *ngFor="let item of list" [value]="item.code">
  <a (click)="setInputText(item.code)">{{item.description}}</a>
</li>
```

Inside this directive I have:

```
@Input() list: any[];
@Input() description: any;
@Input() code: any;
```

On html template of parent component I have declared the directive:

```
<app-search-dropdown [list]="List" [code]="'param1' [description]="'param2'"></app-search-dropdown>
```

I have some types of List like this:

```
List1 = {["one": "1", "two": "2"],["one":"11", "two": "22"]}
List2 = {["uno": "1", "due": "2"],["uno":"11", "due": "22"]}
```

I send to "app-search-dropdown" component a generic array like List1 or List2 and display only a value that pass in [description] and getting a value in [value].

For example:

```
<app-search-dropdown [list]="List1" [code]="'one' [description]="'two'"></app-search-dropdown>
```

I want the rendered template like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of list" [value]="item.one">
<a (click)="setInputText(item.one)">{{item.two}}</a>
</li>
```

How can i do it? Because now I pass [code] and [description] as string and doesn't work.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code and description as key from each item object

```
<a (click)="setInputText(item[code])">{{item[description]}}</a>
```